# Vuetify navigation overlay

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify with vuejs.

How is possible  I know when a "v-navigation-drawer" menu has been opened with overlay(showing above other components/page). It´s occurs depending width screen.

I need check it and disable a component if the 'navigation-drawer' was opened only  without overlay.

Comment: A small tip: with console when you select v-navigation-drawer and type ` $0.__vue__._data.overlay` if it has an overlay it returns an object if not it returns null

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the v-navigation-drawer's `temporary` prop when the navigation drawer is toggled. A/c to docs:

> A temporary drawer sits above its application and uses a scrim (overlay) to darken the background. This drawer behavior is mimicked by default when on mobile.

Will require some code from your side for a more detailed answer.